# How can I only call my data source on time if I have two resolvers that rely on it with Apollo?

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo-server

I have a restaurant query that returns info on my restaurant. The general information that most of my consumers want comes back from restaurant-general-info.com.  There are additional fields though that my consumer might want to know, restaurant-isopen.com, which provides whether or not the restaurant is currently open and the hours that it is open.

I have written two property specific resolvers to handle isOpen and hours as show below:

```
type Query {
    restaurant(name: String): Restaurant
}

type Restaurant {
    name: String!,
    address: String!,
    ownerName: String!,
    isOpen: Boolean!,
    hours: String!
}
```

```
Query: {
    restaurant: async(parent, {name}) => {
        const response = await axios.get(`https://restaurant-general-info.com/${name}`);
        return {
            address: response.address
            ownerName: response.owner
       };
    }
}

Restaurant: {
    isOpen: async(parent) => {
        const response = await axios.get(`https://restaurant-isopen.com/${name}`);
        return response.openNow;   
    },

    hours: async(parent) => {
        const response = await axios.get(`https://restaurant-isopen.com/${name}`);
        return response.hoursOfOperation;   
    }
}
```

The problem is that isOpen and hours share the same data source.  So I don't want to make the same call twice.  I know I could make a property like "open-info" that contains two properties, isOpen and hours, but I don't want the consumers of my graph to need to know / think about how that info is separated differently.

**Is there anyway I can have a resolver that could handle multiple fields?**

ex.

```
isOpen && hours: async(parent) => {
        const response = await axios.get(`https://restaurant-isopen.com/${name}`);
        return {
             isOpen: response.openNow,
             hours: response.hoursOfOperation
        }   
    },
```

**or is there some smarter way of handling this?**

> Note: The APIs are not real

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic situation where using DataLoader is going to help you out a lot.

Here is the JS library, along with some explanations: https://github.com/graphql/dataloader

In short, implementing the DataLoader pattern allows you to batch requests, helping you to avoid the classic N+1 problem in GraphQL and mitigate overfetching, whether that involves your database, querying other services/APIs (as you are here), etc.

Setting up DataLoader and batching the keys you're requesting (in this case, `openNow` and `hoursOfOperation`) will ensure that the axios GET request will only fire once.

Here is a great Medium article to help you visualize how this works behind the scenes: https://medium.com/@__xuorig__/the-graphql-dataloader-pattern-visualized-3064a00f319f